# What's meaning about this in shell?

Tags: shell

Does someone knows the meaning of the code below?

```
#!/bin/sh
files=`find -name *.conifg`
for i in $files
do
  name=${i#*/}
  dir=${name%/*}
done
```

I don't understand the two lines:

```
name=${i#*/}
dir=${name%/*}
```

What's the meaning of "#*/" and "%/*"? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Let's do a test to see its behaviour:

```
$ mypath="this/is/my/path"

$ echo ${mypath#*/}
is/my/path

$ echo ${mypath%/*}
this/is/my
```

So

```
name=${i#*/}   -> gets everything from first slash in $i variable.
dir=${name%/*} -> gets everything up to last slash in $name variable.
```

Taken from the resource:

> **${parameter#word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion (see Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the
>   beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the
>   expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
>   matching pattern (the ‘#’ case). If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
>   pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an
>   array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal
>   operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list.
>
> **${parameter%word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
>   value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of
>   parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) deleted.
>   If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied
>   to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’
>   or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the
>   array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: thanks, fedorqui. BTW, where do you find these? books, online materials or just search it.

Comment: In general I like this sheet: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html (although apparently there are some errors) and then I have my own cheatsheet with examples of them. Then it is a matter of going to http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html and looking for the exact section of the manual.

Comment: Thanks very much, fedorqui.